# How do I put information regarding a random variable into a formula?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I want to apply bayes theorem on a cts rv, but Im stuck at the step of finding the likelihood.

Suppose the probability of A is a function that relies on a random variable y. (ie $\frac{1}{5+5^{5+y}}$)

Next suppose that $Y$~$N(\mu ,\sigma^2)$

I want to find $P(A|Y>k)$ where k is some constant in the domain of y. Do I just need to find a constant $c$ s.t $$c\int_{k}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}} dy =1$$

(Are there better ways of normalising this tail?)

then substitute $c\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}$ into the probability function P(A) defining it on the domain $[k,\infty )$. My idea being that, if we are "given" that $y>k$, then we are just using the right tail of the normal dsn beyond k. However, because we taking only a tail, we need to normalise it, which is why we need to find the constant $c$. Then substituting the pdf of the rv into the function, we get a new random variable, and because we normalised earlier, this new rv will also be normalised.

Is this correct? Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: You need to find the distribution of A. Search for 'functions of random variables'. Then integrate this over the range of A which corresponds to Y>k.